Deuteronomy 31:12 - convert or a Noahide?
I am confused with Deuteronomy 31:12: "the foreigners residing in your towns" this refers to non-Israelites who are living among the Israelites. In Hebrew it's "gerim" (singular: "ger"), which can denote different types of residents; the term can mean "strangers," "sojourners," or "foreigners." But are these references to Noahides or Converts or Future Convert?

I think it usually means converts. But Ibn Ezra says אולי יתיהד.
